# Should I use the same VBO for passing different vertex attributes? Or should I use 2?

Tags: c++, opengl, attributes, shared, vbo

I know the `glVertexAttribPointer` will use the values from the VBO that was bound when it was called. But can you buffer twice onto the same object? Would it replace what was in? Or can you clear a buffer? I don't know if this approach is correct:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); // shared VBO

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);


glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  sizeof(colours),  colours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer(colLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_VERTEX, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Or if I should be using 2 VBOs for buffering the data. What would happen if you call the `glBufferData` function twice to the same bound vertex array object? This is the other way I would think of for doing this:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1); // VBO for vertices

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2); // VBO for colours

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  sizeof(colours),  colours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colLoc);
glVertexAttribPointer(colLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top example won't work as the second glBufferData call will overwrite all of the buffer space in the second one. To properly do that, you have to use the stride and pointer arguments properly, so that the data is interleaved. It's easier (and cleaner imo) to just have multiple VBO's, each storing a separate set of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know what you mean but I was thinking if we could use multiple VBOs. So is it just 1 VBO for every VAO? I heard as well  about the `glBufferSubData` I could use that too. The thing is I want to keep the vertex attirbutes in sepparate C++ arrays and buffer them individually. So I think I would need to use the `glBufferSubData`?

Comment: Multiple VBO's for a VAO was what I was suggesting (maybe my answer didn't make that clear, I will update it), it's what you are doing in the second example. `glBufferSubData` is used to update a portion of VBO,  very useful for updating an existing VBO, but not generally used to initialize it (unless the data is very large, and you may want to send it incrementally)

Comment: ok I get it :D Thanks. But what about the second example then? I was seeing other people's approaches and I think it would work as well. I saw it in this file https://github.com/BennyQBD/ModernOpenGLTutorial/blob/master/mesh.cpp

Comment: Yes your second example is what I am suggesting :)